# forma mas rapida y segura de validar un array php

Tags: php

Tengo este array:

```
$sucursales = array(
    "1" => array("id" => "1","nombre" => "Sucursal 1","direccion" => "Av Sánchez Carrión 843, El Porvenir"),
    "2" => array("id" => "2","nombre" => "Sucursal 2","direccion" => "Av Sánchez Carrión 843, El Porvenir"),
);
```

y para validarlo lo que hago es un

```
if($sucursales[1]){echo "si existe la sucursal";}
```

pero e visto que se puede usar: `array_key_exists();`

**Mi pregunta es: cual de los 2 metodos es mas rapido y eficiente ?**

de ante mano gracias por sus respuestas

Comment: Tu forma no es en ningún caso el mejor camino para determinar si el array tiene un valor en esa llave. El problema es que el código queda expuesto a un eventual *Undefined offset* si se intenta chequear una llave que no existe, por ejemplo: `if($sucursales[3]){echo "si existe la sucursal";}` La decisión está entonces entre `isset`, `empty`, `array_key_exists`, `in_array`  ... pero todo depende del contexto y del uso final que darás al array en sí mismo o al resultado de la validación.

Comment: La pregunta es interesante, pero si las opciones son sólo las dos que indicas, está claro que lo mejor es `array_key_exists` Si te asalta la duda entre `array_key_exists`  e `isset`, el asunto fue tratado en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3210935/5587982) de SO en inglés, con muy buenas respuestas. Cabe decir que PHP tiene también funciones más avanzadas, sobre todo para buscar en arrays complejos, muy anidados, y que incluye también iteradores para contextos aún más avanzados. Sea como sea, lo fundamental para responder a este tipo de preguntas es el contexto.

Comment: el array es solo ese, es simple, son indices simples nada mas, solo que yo quiero siempre e validado con un $sucursales[n]; pero vi que existia la funcion array_key_exists; y la implemente en mi sistema pero note unos microsegundos de mas en cargar mi pagina y alli me entro la duda en cual seria la mejor opcion para validar si un indice existe en mi array sea cual sea (isset, empty, array_key...) lo unico que deseo es que me devuelva true o false y segun eso yo tomo una dedicion con un if...

Answer (score 2):

No te recomendaría en ningún caso que uses esto para verificar:

```
if($sucursales[1]){echo "si existe la sucursal";}
```

Por un lado, el código quedaría expuesto a un *`Undefined offset`*  si el valor no existe en el array.

Además, ahí no estás verificando el array, sino intentando traer lo que hay en ese índice. Hagamos una prueba:

```
var_dump($sucursales[1]);
```

**Salida:**

```
array(3) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["nombre"]=>
  string(10) "Sucursal 1"
  ["direccion"]=>
  string(37) "Av Sánchez Carrión 843, El Porvenir"
}
```

Esto sólo tendría sentido si necesitas esos datos a posteriori.

Para verificar si ese índice existe, podrías hacerlo con `isset`, por lo que he leído es ligeramente más rápido que `array_key_exists()`, pero la diferencia es mínima y apenas se notaría, quizá en arrays muy grandes o en un contexto concurrente.

Otra posibilidad sería con `empty()`.

Todo depende de qué tipo de comportamiento debe observar el código ante ciertos valores. Revisa la documentación y decide:

### [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php)

> Devuelve `true` si var existe y tiene un valor distinto de `null`,
> `false` de lo contrario.

Observa estos dos ejemplos:

```
$sucursales = array(
    "1" => array("id" => "1","nombre" => "Sucursal 1","direccion" => "Av Sánchez Carrión 843, El Porvenir"),
    "2" => array("id" => "2","nombre" => "Sucursal 2","direccion" => "Av Sánchez Carrión 843, El Porvenir"),
);
var_dump(isset($sucursales[1]));


$sucursales = array(
    "1" => null,
    "2" => array("id" => "2","nombre" => "Sucursal 2","direccion" => "Av Sánchez Carrión 843, El Porvenir"),
);

var_dump(isset($sucursales[1]));
```

**Salida:**

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

En el segundo caso `isset()` te está diciendo que no hay una clave `1`, pero sí la hay, sólo que tiene un valor `null` y `isset` no lo detecta.

---

### [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php)

Devuelve `false` si var existe y tiene un valor no vacío, distinto de cero. De otro modo devuelve `true`.

Los siguientes valores son considerados como vacíos:

- `""` (una cadena vacía)
- `0` (0 como un integer)
- `0.0` (0 como un float)
- `"0"` (0 como un string)
- `null`
- `false`
- `array()` (un array vacío)

Como podrás apreciar, `empty()` es más estricto y podría ser muy útil cuando no quieres dejar pasar valores nulos, en blanco, en cero, falsos, etc ... todo lo dicho en la definición de *vacío* más arriba.

Veamos dos ejemplos:

```
$sucursales = array(
    "1" => array("id" => "1","nombre" => "Sucursal 1","direccion" => "Av Sánchez Carrión 843, El Porvenir"),
    "2" => array("id" => "2","nombre" => "Sucursal 2","direccion" => "Av Sánchez Carrión 843, El Porvenir"),
);
var_dump(!empty($sucursales[1]));


$sucursales = array(
    "1" => "",
    "2" => array("id" => "2","nombre" => "Sucursal 2","direccion" => "Av Sánchez Carrión 843, El Porvenir"),
);

var_dump(!empty($sucursales[1]));
```

**Saida:**

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

En el segundo caso hay una cadena vacía y `empty` te da 'false`. Aquí` isset `te daría`true`. Nótese que aquí` empty`se usa en negativo`!` para la evaluación, por su naturaleza misma.

---

### [`array_key_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-key-exists.php)

Verifica si el índice o clave dada existe en el array.

- `array_key_exists()` devuelve `true` si la key dada existe en el array. La key puede ser cualquier valor posible para índice de un array.
- devuelte `true` en caso de éxito o `false` en caso de error.
- `array_key_exists()` buscará las claves en la primera dimensión solamente. Las claves anidadas en arrays multidimensionales no se encontrarán. Para arrays más complejos es mejor usar otras funciones avanzadas de PHP.
- `isset()` no retorna `true` para claves de array que correspondan a un valor `null`, mientras que `array_key_exists()` si lo hace.

Veamos algunos ejemplos:

```
$sucursales = array(
    "1" => array("id" => "1","nombre" => "Sucursal 1","direccion" => "Av Sánchez Carrión 843, El Porvenir"),
    "2" => array("id" => "2","nombre" => "Sucursal 2","direccion" => "Av Sánchez Carrión 843, El Porvenir"),
);

var_dump(array_key_exists(1,$sucursales));


$sucursales = array(
    "1" => 0,
    "2" => array("id" => "2","nombre" => "Sucursal 2","direccion" => "Av Sánchez Carrión 843, El Porvenir"),
);
var_dump(array_key_exists(1,$sucursales));


$sucursales = array(
    "1" => null,
    "2" => array("id" => "2","nombre" => "Sucursal 2","direccion" => "Av Sánchez Carrión 843, El Porvenir"),
);
var_dump(array_key_exists(1,$sucursales));


$sucursales = array(
    "1" => "",
    "2" => array("id" => "2","nombre" => "Sucursal 2","direccion" => "Av Sánchez Carrión 843, El Porvenir"),
);
var_dump(array_key_exists(1,$sucursales));
```

**Salida:**

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

Podemos decir que es casi igual que `isset()`, a diferencia de que no ignora los nulos.

### Conclusión

- El más rápido es `isset()` (según varias respuestas de SO y las notas del Manual de PHP), pero no debes confiar en él si quieres tomar en cuenta los nulos. En ese caso, `array_key_exists` sería la mejor opción.
- Y si quieres que no pasen los valores vacíos, usa `empty`.

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta que este array es estatico, yo lo manejo directamente no varia, la mejor opcion seria isset si por ejemplo alguien quiere acceder al array $sucursales[3] y este no existe, yo no le pondre null ni 0 simplemente no lo pondre el indice 3